# Relation between exponential map and parallel transport

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm starting to learn Riemannian geometry and have a question.

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a Riemannian manifold, $p \in \mathcal{M}$; $\tau_{p}^{q}$ be a parallel transport from $p$ to $q$ and $\operatorname{exp}_p$ be an exponential map. The question is: given a smooth curve $\gamma : [a, b] \to \mathcal{M}$ such that $\gamma([a, b]) \subset \mathcal{U}$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is some neighborhood of $p$ where $\operatorname{exp}_p, \tau_{p}^{(\cdot)}$, are defined, is it true that
>   \begin{equation}
>     \left(
>       \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}
>       \operatorname{exp}_p^{-1}\gamma 
>     \right)(t)
>   = \tau_{\gamma(t)}^{p}\dot{\gamma}(t) \,?
> \end{equation}

Comment: It certainly works in $\Bbb R^n$. What have you tried doing?

Comment: You mean during what process arose this question or what have I tried to do to prove it? :)

Comment: Your proof attempts.

Comment: Let $g$ be a metric tensor on $\mathcal{M}$. I've tired to use countiniuty of $g$ together with the fact that for any $p \in \mathcal{M}$ and for $u, v \in T_p\mathcal{M}$, if $g(u, u)=g(v,v)$ and angle between $u$ and $v$ is zero, then $u=v$.

Comment: I think I found counterexample -- it is the sphere. The distance between geodesics change, and because of that the left side may be scaled result of right side. It seems that it can be fixed by adding the value of  [Jacobi field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_field) in some way.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between parallel transport and derivative of the exponential map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345623/difference-between-parallel-transport-and-derivative-of-the-exponential-map)

Comment: The question doesn't make sense as stated: the parallel transport operator $\tau$ is only defined along a curve. As stated $\gamma$ does not necessarily pass through $p$. //   In regards to the vote to close as duplicate: in the proposed duplicate the analogue to $\gamma$ is explicitly required to be a geodesic through the point $p$. This assumption is not made here.

Comment: @WillieWong: The OP has inverted the order of the sentences: first he (incorrectly, as you noticed) talks about the parallel transport between two points, and then he (correctly) performs it along the curve $\gamma$. It is a minor mistake in my opinion, and the ideas contained therein are quite clear to a professional despite the slightly sloppy formulation.